# How do I save a table to a flash?

Tags: core-flight-system

How do I save a table to a flash? I have a table that has had one or more fields modified.

I call CFE_TBL_Update it tells me the are CFE_TBL_INFO_NO_UPDATE_PENDING even thought the table has been updated.

I tried forcing additional updates for testing and it did not work.

Then it of course does not save the data. I also tried CFE_TBL_DumpToBuffer and it to did not work.